# Replacing 'Null' with NULL

Tags: mysql, null

I have a database that through an error in a php script had a lot of values entered into it as the string 'Null' instead of the actual NULL value. Is there anyway to find all 'Null' strings in a table and replace them with NULL instead of having to search each column?

Comment: Why not run a query many times? (Each time for each column) Otherwise, the problem gets very complex

Comment: I would have about 250 seperate queries to run - I'd prefer to find a simpler way!

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = NULL
WHERE columnName = 'Null'
```

Comment: `instead of having to search each column` => Your solution will need to be searched for every column

Comment: I would argue that there is no way to update ANY value without first searching for it therefore there is NO WAY of doing this without searching every column(in some form or another)...it seems John didn't feel like noting that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with one `update` and multiple columns:

```
UPDATE t
    SET col1 = (case when col1 = 'NULL' then NULL else col1 end),
        col2 = (case when col2 = 'NULL' then NULL else col2 end),
        ... ;
```

If you have lots of columns and don't want to write all the code, you can run a query like:

```
select replace('XXX = (case when XXX = \'NULL\' then NULL else XXX end),',
               'XXX', column_name)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = YOURTABLENAME ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Instead of having to search each column". If there are many columns, and you don't want to run a query as suggested by @john-conde as many times, then the alternative is to dump your database to a plain text file using

```
 mysqldump -u<user> -p<password> --database <dbname> > dbdump.sql
```

This dumps your database as plain text into a file by the name `dbdump.sql`. You can use any find/replace technique you are familiar with (such as sed, awk, perl, vi) on `dbdump.sql`. You just have to be extra careful about what and where you are replacing. You should ensure that you are only replacing strings that matter. Once you do that, you can load the dump back into mysql like this

```
mysql -u<user> -p<password> <dbname> < dbdump.sql
```

You can also dump one table at a time -> fix it -> load it back.

If you are doing this in production, extra precaution is required to ensure no writes happen to the db while you are performing this operation. `mysqldump` takes several other options on command line which help in dumping consistent snapshot of the database.